# What is a fine MySQL class for Python?

Tags: database, python, mysql

I am new to python,earlier I used to develop in PHP. 
With PHP, I used MySQL as the back end Database.There I had different libraries,MySQL classes with easy to use functions available open , also we used an internally developed MySQL classes to work with the database operations.
MySQL helper classes with functions written to manage queries.Such as a Pre-defined functions which could be invoked to do specific operation.

For example:

If I am giving an associative array to be inputted into the MySQL,where keys are field names and values ,the associated values for the MySQL row.

In this case,the function would normally takes the array split it and help in DB insertion.It also would look into common issues like SQL injection.

**Now with python,I started using MySQLdb with basic queries.I would like to know if there any fine and reliable helper classes with MySQL functions written in the 'Pythonic' way optimized for MySQL?**

Please advice

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically: What are the requirements such a class should fulfil? What features it should (at least) support?

Comment: @Izzy I have added more information to the question.

Comment: Thanks, better already. Have you checked the linked page on our Meta site? I'm still missing a bullet-pointed list of requirements, which makes them much easier to reference (not a must, but makes things easier for those who might be able to help you).

Comment: A little late, but [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/bl9pj/what_is_the_python_equivalent_to_pdo/) is helpful